# IE dosnt support my web

Tags: html, css

I'm a bigginer for HTML5 and CSS3. I create home page but it is not working on IE browser. My `nav` tag is not working in IE. and style sheet also not working. Plese someone help me.

## This is my CSS

```
/*-----------------------
Navigation
-------------------------*/

nav ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    float:right;
}
nav ul li{
    list-style:none;
    float:left;

}
header nav ul li a{
    display:block;
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:20px;
}
header nav ul li a:hover{
    background:#67A6B8;
}
header nav ul li a:active{
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)insert;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)insert; 
    box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)insert;
}
```

## This is my HTML page

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">NEWS</a></li>
        <li><a href="">SERVICE</a></li>
        <li><a href="">COMPANY</a></li>
        <li><a href="">RECRUITE</a></li>
        <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Highly opinionated politically incorrect suggestion: if you have no explicit reason to support these old, _obsolete_ browsers, then don't. They are just holding the web back. If a user still refuses to abandon his/her stone-age-era browser in 2016, let them keep going with their already broken web experience (we are talking about less than one percent of all users here (http://caniuse.com)).

Answer (score 0):

`HTML5` is relatively new.

Browsers won’t apply any default styling to the new elements like your `<nav>`.

So - as you - almost all people declare some styling (in `CSS`) for them, at least that they should force a line break:

```
section, article, header, footer, nav, aside, hgroup {
display: block;
}
```

That’s enough for most browsers.

Internet Explorer versions 6, 7 and 8 have special needs for the these new elements. They resolutely refuses to recognize the new elements unless an exemplar of each element is first created with `JavaScript`, like this:

```
document.createElement('nav');
```

So you have to write an `JavaScript` file for these new elements and include it in the `<head>` of your page in a conditional comment and after any `stylesheets`, like this:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="My_sript.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Or you may use more advanced solution like [The HTML5 Shiv](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv).

Comment: Thank you very much  for your answer. now it is working.

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider accept and upvote my answer, if it was useful for you.

Comment: Regarding votes, you need downvote, as the question is clearly Off-Topic and eligible to get closed. Please refer to [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more information. You should avoid answering off-topic questions in future